# When adding dependency: CDI deployment failure, Unsatisfied dependencies for type Set<Service> with qualifiers @Default

Tags: maven, twitter, glassfish, twitter4j, twitter-hbc

When I add the twitter hbc dependency to my pom.xml I'm getting an error. 
I followed the instructions from [here.](https://github.com/twitter/hbc) I don't get it, if it was a dependency problem I should have found a fix on the web but if I comment out that dependency, my server is starting..

this is my what I added to my pom.xml:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbc-core</artifactId> <!-- or hbc-twitter4j -->
      <version>2.2.0</version> <!-- or whatever the latest version is -->
    </dependency>
```

This is the error:

```
2015-06-20T18:13:52.877+0200|Severe: Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Set<Service> with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager(Set<Service>)
  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager.<init>(ServiceManager.java:0)
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Set<Service> with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager(Set<Service>)
  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager.<init>(ServiceManager.java:0)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:370)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:291)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:165)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:529)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:515)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:490)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:419)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.ReDeployCommand.execute(ReDeployCommand.java:131)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## In Short:

Use a newer version of Guava.

## Explanation

I guess, you have Guava 14 or 15 on your class path. The class `com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager` contains an `@Inject` expecting a `Set` of services. This dependency is not available, and the container raises a `DeploymentException`.

### The solutions

- Use a newer Guava version (at least 16, the fix was introduced there, see [this commit](https://github.com/google/guava/commit/8f062a880a3102d6d8f909c0754d3d2cd468c9dd#diff-7e608168f8a7027309000f11beafe7bb))
- Disable CDI
- Implement a tiny producer

  ```
  @Produces Set<Service> dummyServices() {
    return new HashSet<>();
  }
  ```

### Further docs:

- https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1433
- https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1433

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I didn't add such thing as guava. I did now with the newest version and it works. I'm left wondering where it came from though and while it is working I feel like me adding the newest version to my pom.xml might be a band aid fix.

Comment: Guava is a transient dependency of twitter's `hbc-core`, see https://github.com/twitter/hbc/blob/master/hbc-core/pom.xml. You can inspect dependencies by invoking `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: Upgrading Guava is probably the best route, but if you can't, you can disable CDI on a per-deploy basis in GlassFish. Just uncheck "Implicit CDI" on the Admin Console when deploying.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for this solution. I am using **Twilio SMS API** which requires `guava-14.0.1.jar` as dependency. I was getting exception as

```
org.glassfish.deployment.common.deploymentexception: CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Set<Service>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager(Set<Service>)]
```

I've upgraded the jar to `guava-16.0.1.jar` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Add the last version of Guava to your pom.xml file.
That will solve your problem.